# QtCreator - fresh installation - 2 errors

Tags: macos, qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2

I have just done a fresh installation of Qt 5 on macOS Mojave along with QtCreator, and starting from scratch with a very basic QtQuick app, I get two strange errors:

**1) No matching function call to 'connect'**

[image: connect]

This is the project after creation without any modification. Whats wrong here? On my other mac at work I didnt have this. I even just completely uninstalled/reinstalled QT, but no change. The code **compiles and runs just fine**, so this seems to be just a display issue?!

**2) toolBar property not found in ApplicationWindow**

Ok so I am new to QtQuick, but according to examples and docs, `ApplicationWindow` should have a `toolBar` property?

Yet:
[image: toolBar]

```
qrc:/main.qml:31 Cannot assign to non-existent property "toolBar"
```

What am I overlooking? Could someone help out?

Comment: What Qt version did you install? Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as a text, not an image.

Comment: I've installed Qt Creator 4.10.2 along with Qt 5.13.2. The minimal example is creating a new empty QtQuick application using the project wizard, as stated above.
To be honest, I have worked further on the project, and Qt Creator is showing errors all over the place, yet everything compiles fine. For example, here `QStringList comps = line.split(";");` (`line` beeing `QString`) it complains that `comps` does not have the member `length`, yet every `QList` instance does, and I can use it just fine.

Comment: When it comes to `toolBar` it exists in QtQuickControls 1.x, but not in version 2.x. Please paste complete code samples. It would be better to ask two separate questions.